# kernel project des encryption

Tags: c

In a kernel level project I want to encrypt a packet using des algorithm , need to use the function

```
static int des_setkey(void *ctx,const u8 *key,
                         unsigned int keylen, 
                         u32 *flags)
```

I want to know how the key to be passed to the function , which value to be used as the to the key , its a pointer type so will be an address value

Comment: It is a bit difficult to say without further context. Is this part of some publicly available library? Do you have any documentation about this function? Typically, DES takes a 56 + 8= 64 bit key. The flags parameter probably sets the mode of operation (which may or may not require you to define an initialization vector).

Comment: I can see why you have had trouble finding answers for this, the linux kernel has changed.  There is also no actual included use of this in the kernel at all.

Answer (score 1):

http://lxr.kelp.or.kr/ident?v=2.6.28;i=des_setkey

```
* Cryptographic API.
*
* s390 implementation of the DES Cipher Algorithm.
*
* Copyright IBM Corp. 2003,2007
* Author(s): Thomas Spatzier
*            Jan Glauber (jan.glauber@de.ibm.com)
```

typeA A=xy;
functionname(typeA* a, typeA b)
--> functionname(&A,A);

```
crypto_des_check_key(const u8 *key, unsigned int keylen, u32 *flags)
{
        u32 n, w;

        n  = parity[key[0]]; n <<= 4;
        n |= parity[key[1]]; n <<= 4;
        n |= parity[key[2]]; n <<= 4;
        n |= parity[key[3]]; n <<= 4;
        n |= parity[key[4]]; n <<= 4;
        n |= parity[key[5]]; n <<= 4;
        n |= parity[key[6]]; n <<= 4;
        n |= parity[key[7]];
        w = 0x88888888L;

        if ((*flags & CRYPTO_TFM_REQ_WEAK_KEY)
            && !((n - (w >> 3)) & w)) {  /* 1 in
```

-->CRYPTO_TFM_REQ_WEAK_KEY is a flag
--> source/include/linux/crypto.h

```
/*
* Transform masks and values (for crt_flags).
*/
#define CRYPTO_TFM_REQ_MASK             0x000fff00
#define CRYPTO_TFM_RES_MASK             0xfff00000

#define CRYPTO_TFM_REQ_WEAK_KEY         0x00000100
#define CRYPTO_TFM_REQ_MAY_SLEEP        0x00000200
#define CRYPTO_TFM_REQ_MAY_BACKLOG      0x00000400
#define CRYPTO_TFM_RES_WEAK_KEY         0x00100000
#define CRYPTO_TFM_RES_BAD_KEY_LEN      0x00200000
#define CRYPTO_TFM_RES_BAD_KEY_SCHED    0x00400000
#define CRYPTO_TFM_RES_BAD_BLOCK_LEN    0x00800000
#define CRYPTO_TFM_RES_BAD_FLAGS        0x01000000
```

source/arch/s390/crypto/des_s390.c

```
#define DES_EXPKEY_WORDS        32
typedef unsigned char           u8;
typedef unsigned char           u8;
typedef unsigned short          u16;
typedef unsigned int            u32;
typedef unsigned long long      u64;
typedef signed char             s8;
typedef short                   s16;
typedef int                     s32;
typedef long long               s64;



static int des_setkey(void *ctx, const u8 *key, unsigned int keylen, u32 *flags)
{
         return setkey(((struct des_ctx *)ctx)->expkey, key, keylen, flags);
}



struct des_ctx {
        u32 expkey[DES_EXPKEY_WORDS];
};
```

Comment: answers need more constructive text or at least comments if it is code.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it is from the 2.6.16 (ish) linux kernel. Later kernels have seen the crypto system api re-written slightly.

for this kernel this might help:-

- *key is a pointer to a 16 byte array, ( unsigned char[16] ).
- *ctx is a pointer to a struct des_ctx structure;
- *flags is a pointer to a 32bit unsigned int that will have CRYPTO_TFM_RES_WEAK_KEY set if you have supplied a weak key ( one that fails FIPS 74 - see the ekey() function )